# running TCL through python by subprocess, but not giving any output

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, eval, subprocess

I am trying to run my tcl script through python subprocess as follow:

```
import subprocess
>>> subprocess.Popen(["tclsh", "tcltest.tcl"])
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x0000000001DD4DD8>
>>> subprocess.Popen(["tclsh", "tcltest.tcl"], shell=True )
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x0000000002B34550>
```

I don't know if it is working or not, since I don't see any anything from it!
my tcl script also has some packages from my company that causes errors when I use Tkinter, Tk, and  eval,

```
import Tkinter
import socket

def TCLRun():
 s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
 s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 5006))
 root = Tkinter.Tk()
## root.tk.eval('package require Azimuth-Sdk')
 tcl_script ="""
##package require Company-Sdk
## set players [ace_azplayer_list_players]
set players 2
puts $players 
##  if { $players != "" } {         
##  foreach player $players {   
##      set cmd ace_azplayer_remove_player
##      if { [catch { [ $cmd $player ] } err] } {   
##          puts " $cmd $player - $err" 
##          sleep 1 
##          }           
##      } 
##  } """
 # call the Tkinter tcl interpreter
 root.tk.call('eval', tcl_script)
 root.mainloop()
```

gives me this error

```
import TCLCall
>>> TCLCall.TCLRun()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    TCLCall.TCLRun()
  File "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\PKT\TCLCall.py", line 24, in TCLRun
    root.tk.call('eval', tcl_script)
TclError: can not find channel named "stdout"
```

that's why I switched to subprocess. at least it doesn't give me error!

any idea how to run my tcl script with internal required package through python?!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To get the output from using `subprocess.Popen`, you can try the following:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(
    "tclsh tcltest.tcl",
    shell=True,
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
print stdout
print stderr
```

It's entirely possible that the script you're running with `subprocess.Popen` is also generating an error, but isn't displaying since you aren't explicitly looking for it.

**Edit:**

To prevent some information from being lost in the comments below:

You probably have several potential errors here, or things you can try.

Either your tcl script by itself isn't able to import `teapot` properly, or some sort of interaction between the tcl script and the python script isn't working properly, or `subprocess.Popen` isn't correctly finding the `teapot` package from your path.

I would try debugging your programs in that order. First confirm that your tcl script works without using python or `subprocess.Popen` and just directly run it from the command line (for example, `C:\Users\blah tclsh tcltest.tcl`)

Then, after you've made sure your script work, bring in Python. From what I'm seeing, you don't have any problem with the python stuff, but with either your tcl script or some issue with your path.

Comment: import subprocess
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(
 'tcltest.tcl',
 shell=True,
 stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
 stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
 stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
>>> print stdout

>>> print stderr
 it just opened my script (by notepad++)

Comment: @Amir -- do you maybe have to do `['tclsh', 'tcltest.tcl']` like you did in your example above?

Comment: what do u mean? should I add this ['tclsh', 'tcltest.tcl'] to the end of your answer?

Comment: @Amir -- I edited my answer. Can you try rerunning it and seeing what happens?

Comment: import subprocess
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(
 ["tclsh", "tcltest.tcl"],
 shell=True,
 stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
 stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
 stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
>>> print stdout

>>> print stderr
can't find package __teapot__

    while executing

"package require __teapot__"


>>>

Comment: @Amir -- What happens if you directly run the tcl script from the command line? Does it give the same error? Also, I edited my answer again. idk if the edit will work now, but give it a shot.

Comment: import subprocess
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(
 "tclsh tcltest.tcl",
 shell=True,
 stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
 stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
 stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> stdout , stderr= p.communicate()
>>> print stdout

>>> print sdterr

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#49>", line 1, in <module>
    print sdterr
NameError: name 'sdterr' is not defined
>>> print stderr
can't find package __teapot__

    while executing

"package require __teapot__"

Comment: I believe the problem is the package that my script requires! it's not finding it! what do u think?

Comment: What happens if you just go directly to the command line, bypassing the python script altogether and doing `tclsh tcltest.tcl`?

Comment: should the script be in C:\Python27\ folder?

Comment: do u mean something like this?

Comment: import os   os.system("tclsh tclstest.tcl")

Comment: thank you so much, that was very helpful. actually, I ran my tcl script and it's working. the reason makes me feel there are some issues with finding the package is, I tried to run a simple command of tcl from my package like, package requires ..., then one command from that package, I tried to do this by import Tkinter and eval, it alsways gave me error that cannot find the package!

Comment: @Amir -- hmm, then I have no idea. What you might try doing is opening a new question, but this time asking why you don't seem to be able to import tcl packages when running them using subprocess.Popen. You might be able to get more help that way, since getting output from subprocess.popen isn't really related to the root issue

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of `subprocess.Popen` is redirection of standard channels, so you can handle output programmatically instead of seeing it on your own standard output. Did you try handling it? How?

Maybe you don't need redirection at all: then `os.system("tclsh tcltest.tcl")` should be enough. Or maybe `subprocess.Popen` has other advantages for you -- then figure out how to disable redirection, or how to redirect child's stdout to your own stdout.

Comment: thanks,os.system("tclsh tcltest.tcl")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    os.system("tclsh tcltest.tcl")
NameError: name 'os' is not defined

Comment: You have to `import os` before you call `os.system`.

Comment: so, it means, it runs the tcl by tcl interpreter?

Comment: import os
>>> os.system("tclsh tcltest.tcl")
1

Comment: if so, that would be great, that's exactly what I need. then I will find a way to get access to outputs. first I just need to run this script through python(my bigger problem is having package requires ,,, in my script!)

Comment: Don't try to debug everything at once: first, ensure the script works when you run `tclsh tcltest.tcl` by hand (in your shell prompt). Then debug Tcl/Python interaction. And when you want to process your script's output in Python, then you'll have to use `subprocess.Popen` again.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have a solution for you. Or at least a different method to try. This example opens the TCL shell as a process. Then you pump commands to it as though you are on command line. Since you said your command line worked, I would think that this would too. This works for me on Windows with Python 3.7.6 and TCL 8.5.

There needs to be a little trickery. I've found solutions that require threads and all sorts of other overhead to get this job done but they just fell flat. What I came up with is simple and synchronous.

stdout.readline() will block. So if your TCL command doesn't throw anything back, you are dead in the water.

SO, you force something to come back by appending an innocuous TCL puts command that communicates back to the Python script that the job is done.

The other trick is that you need to "puts []" the command to force the output back into stdout.

If you need to source more TCL files, then add those in before you make your final call to what you are trying to run. Whatever you need to do on the cli, you do through this process.

My code has this all wrapped in a class with methods. I brought them all together here in-line for the example. Leave the errorInfo code in while debugging and remove as you see fit.

<s>Note: You can also use TCL "info body " to read a script into a string variable and then run each line through the process. In essence, if in a Python debugging session, stepping through TCL.</s> Sorry, this does not work too well. The workaround for comments does not work for opening curly braces.

Hope this helps someone out there.

EDIT: Using multi-line string handles comment lines.

```
import subprocess

print("------")
shell_path = r"<YOUR PATH TO THE TCL INTERPRETER SHELL>"
tcl_shell = subprocess.Popen(shell_path,
                    stdin =subprocess.PIPE,
                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                    universal_newlines = True,
                    bufsize = 0)

#
# Use ONE of the "command"s below. I have them here in series for exmaples.
#

# Simple
command = r"set temp 5"

# Multiline with error --> This will give an error of course to see the error extraction in action
command = r"""
    set temp 5
    set temp2 [expr temp + 5]
"""

# Multiline working
command = r"""
    set temp 5
    set temp2 [expr $temp + 5]
"""

# More output
command = r"""
    puts "Starting process"
    set temp 5
    puts $temp
    set temp2 [expr $temp + 5]
"""

# Comments handled
command = r"# comment!"

# Be sure to leave the newline to handle comments
tcl_shell.stdin.write(f"""puts [{command}
                                ] \nputs \"tcl_shell_cmd_complete\"\n""")
# NOTE: tcl_shell.stdin.flush() does not seem to be needed. Consider if needed.
result = ""
line = tcl_shell.stdout.readline()
while line != "tcl_shell_cmd_complete\n":
    result += line
    line = tcl_shell.stdout.readline()

print(f"tcl_shell sent:\n{command}")
print(f"tcl_shell result:\n{result}".rstrip())

command_error_check = "puts $errorInfo"
tcl_shell.stdin.write(f"{command_error_check} \nputs \"tcl_shell_cmd_complete\"\n")
resultErr = ""
line = tcl_shell.stdout.readline()
while line != "tcl_shell_cmd_complete\n":
    resultErr += line
    line = tcl_shell.stdout.readline()

print(f"tcl_shell error info:\n{resultErr}")

tcl_shell.stdin.close()
tcl_shell.terminate()
tcl_shell.wait(timeout=0.5)
print("------")
```