# I need to run a TCL script in python, my TCL script also has a user-defined(internal) package

Tags: python, tcl

I need to run a TCL script in python, my TCL script also has a user-defined(internal) package 
I tried these scripts:

**1.**

```
import Tkinter
import socket

def TCLRun():
 s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
 s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 5006))
 root = Tkinter.Tk()
## root.tk.eval('package require XXX')
 tcl_script ="""
package require XXX
set YYY [COMMAND FROM PACKAGE]
puts $YYY 
} """
 # call the Tkinter tcl interpreter
 root.tk.call('eval', tcl_script)
 root.mainloop()
```

with this error:

```
import TCLCall
>>> TCLCall.TCLRun()

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
        TCLCall.TCLRun()
      File "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\PKT\TCLCall.py", line 24, in TCLRun
        root.tk.call('eval', tcl_script)
    TclError: can not find channel named "stdout"
```

and,

**2.**

```
import Tkinter
root=Tkinter.Tk()
root.tk.eval('package require XXX')
root.tk.eval('set YYY COMMAND')
```

returns error about sdtout!

other one:

**3.**

```
 import subprocess
    p = subprocess.Popen(
        "tclsh tcltest.tcl",
        shell=True,
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
    print stdout
    print stderr
```

returns the following error:

```
can't find package __teapot__

    while executing

"package require __teapot__"
```

none of them working, please help me with this issue!

I can use some commands that operating something on our product with following code:

```
import socket
import time

def Sckt():
 s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
 s.connect(('127.0.0.1', 5006))

 s.send('0 COMMAND \r\n')
```

that would give you some ideas!

thank,

Comment: are you sure the tcl-code is running as standalone?  
try `tclsh tcltest.tcl`  
the errors seem to come from tcl, so the python around your tcl might only make it harder to understand the underlying problem.

Comment: Yes, I ran the script several times and it works. the problem is from python that doesn't recognize it!

Comment: I added an answer in another question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61623719/5626983

Answer (score 1):

With a custom package that is not part of your vendor's installation, you need to instruct Tcl where to search for it from. To do that, append the *parent* directory of the directory containing the package to Tcl's global `auto_path` variable. For example, if the XXX package is in the directory `/home/amir/.tclpackages/XXX1.0` then you would have your script do this:

```
lappend auto_path /home/amir/.tclpackages
```

This can go anywhere in the Tcl script before the `package require XXX`. (Well, you could put it afterwards but then the `package require` would fail…)

Comment: actually I added that command to my tcl script. but my problem is if I should put that package in my python27 folder?